# Issue with BASIC HTTP authentication using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, http, authentication, selenium

I am trying to test a web app that has BASIC authentication (there is a popup that comes up to authenticate the user when I hit whatever page, the popup is not part of the HTML). After entering the username/password and clicking OK on the popup the main login page appears.

Now, I need to a strategy to authenticate the user in Firefox on the popup. I tried the following looking at some old atricles in the Stack Overflow and this is not working for me.

Can some please guide me how to proceed? I have Selenium 2.5.0 installed and using python for scripting.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "website url")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://username:password@WebsiteURL")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this user:password scheme working you need to set another preference:

```
profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
```

[Reference](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length)

Btw, you are using very old version of Selenium.

Comment: Hello Erki.. I have tried the avbove too and it didn't work for some reason.